# "power off and on" specifc usb port

Tags: power-management

I am trying to power off and power  on  usb port in Ubuntu 12.04 without success.

I tried the steps listed below:

```
echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/$port/power/autosuspend"
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/$port/power/level"
```

and

```
 echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.3/power/control"
 echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.3/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
```

and

```
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/XXXX/power/level
```

Comment: Same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/342061/power-on-off-usb-port-in-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: how doesn't work?