# How to copy or (quickly-and-easily) backup a "special file"?

Tags: usb, nautilus, backup

Wanting to try this [unverified answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1030845) for this [unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498950/possible-to-electronically-disconnect-the-fingerprint-sensor-on-my-laptop), but not without some kind of quick-and-easy backup. Thought copy-and-paste of the **`/dev/bus/usb/004` folder** would do the trick, but that doesn't work (yet), as its contents (001 and 002) appear to be "special files" which cannot be simply copied:

> Can't copy special file

- Any idea how to quickly backup (and/or copy-paste) such files?
- Would you expect different behaviour of **Command line** *vs.* **Nautilus/GUI** ?

[image]

<sup>Related but different: https://askubuntu.com/questions/472189/enable-copying-of-special-files-in-gui.</sup>

Comment: I have been a few years. Have you figured out why it doesn't work and / or how to make it work. I just needed to copy back a few files I saved on an external HDD. I backed it up with the terminal per `sudo cp -R` and copied it back as a normal user via Nautilus. I got this message for several files of Dropbox and for one file of Copy (also a cloud service).

Answer (score 2):

The files in /dev/ folder are special, in a way that they represent
devices on the machine, and are not regular files that have content
in them. That file probably represents a flash drive you plugged in
to your computer, or a USB bus. If it's a USB flash drive, mounting
it first, then copying it's contents will do the trick. You could
also try backing up the whole disk as an image.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount - how to mount.
[How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) - check the answer about 'dd' and 'gparted' utilities.